# Instagram API does not show content

Tags: instagram-api

I'm using 1 client to get 2 feeds based on a tag from Instagram. I'm using the same accesstoken for both feeds. I get the information I want for 1 feed, but the other one the returnvalue is as follows:

```
{
   "pagination": {
      "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
   },
   "data": [],
   "meta": {
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

The url is for both the API calls I use is https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/[TAG]/media/recent?access_token=[ACCESS.TOKEN]. I can't find the right solution

Answer (score 0):

Are you on sandbox mode?

In sandbox mode, only 'invited' users and their accounts can be worked on. You can't get information about other peoples accounts.

Comment: Yes, I'm on sandboxmode. But the same access token is used in the other call, and that is working fine.

Comment: If you can add the code for both calls, I can help.

Comment: $instagramfeed = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/[TAG]/media/recent?access_token=[ACCESS.TOKEN] ');
$instagramphotos = json_decode($instagramfeed, true);